# How do I get two specific key values from the IndexedDB Object Store?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I need to get specific two key "Art","Time" values from indexeddb objectstore,
but objectstore only returns the "Art" key value.

```
window.indexedDB.open('idb',3).onsuccess = function(e){
db = e.target.result;
    db.transaction('objstore','readonly').objectStore('objstore').get("Art","Time").onsuccess = async function(e){ 
    
        const r = e.target.result;
        console.log(r); // returns only "Art" key value...
  
    }
}
```